# Changing my lastname to A

Tags: research-process, collaboration

It is well-studied that a last-name starting with $a$ has a positive impact on research career:

[https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2803164#:~:text=It%20has%20been%20argued%20that,avoiding%20collaborations%20with%20multiple%20authors](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2803164#:%7E:text=It%20has%20been%20argued%20that,avoiding%20collaborations%20with%20multiple%20authors).

So I decided to change my last name upon marriage. Will there be any unknown negative consequence for this practice?

Comment: One consequence is that you won't know whether your accomplishments are gained legitimately or only gifted to you by virtue of your A name.

Comment: I think it makes sense.

Comment: Do you already have significant accomplishments in a CV?

Comment: We have a lot of existing Q&A on name changes, for a variety of reasons; I think you'll find all the possible pitfalls and suggestions to work around them on those other questions, making this one somewhat redundant. I collected a few as duplicates but you can also simply search "name change" and find many more.